# MySQL: Return SUCCESS after operation

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a software, which is used by 2 users at a time, they interact together in several steps. Sometimes one user has to wait for the other, until he has inserted the data into a database.  Then the same data has to be retrieved again.
The confusing is, that sometimes I then receive all data, sometimes only parts and sometimes even nothing from the database, without changing the code.
Is it possible, that I just retrieve it "too fast"? The retrieving happens **milliseconds** after inserting. Maybe the database needs some time for the operation.
**If so, is it possible to receive something like a "success-message", that everything has been inserted?**

This the inserting function. It is called within a loop several times and inserts some data. After, it updates the flag *ready* in another table:

```
public void insert(String name, int id) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES (?)");
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE session set ready = 1 WHERE id = ?");
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Then, these both functions check every second, if the flag *ready* from the other user has been set.

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (DB.INSTANCE.check(5)) {
                // retrieving data from database...
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

If the flag is set, it returns *true* and the function above then retrieves the data again.

```
public boolean check(int id) {
    boolean notify = false;
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM session WHERE id = ?");
        stmt.setString(1, id);
        stmt.executeQuery();
        while (stmt.getResultSet().next()) {
            if (stmt.getResultSet().getInt("ready") == 1) {
                notify = true;
            }
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return notify;
}
```

This is my solution so far, which unfortunately doesn't work, as described above.

**EDIT**
This function is called when the flag is set:

```
public void load() {
    data= DB.INSTANCE.loadChosen(id);
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        model.addElement("Nothing!");
    } else {
        for (Map.Entry e : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue());
            model.addElement(e.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

It is being literated and put into a model (JList).
This is the corresponding function in the database class:

```
public HashMap load(int id) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id LIKE ?");
        stmt.setString(1, id);
        stmt.executeQuery();
        while (stmt.getResultSet().next()) {
            String name = stmt.getResultSet().getString("name");
            int coe1 = stmt.getResultSet().getInt("coe1");
            chosenNames.put(name, coe1);
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return data;
}
```

The actual data retrieved is not really important, these are just names and numbers, everything is put in a HashMap.
When I return the data in the console, even there are some of them missing sometimes, altough they ARE in the database.

Comment: Out of interest, what transaction isolation level are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard about it...

Comment: Is `id` a primary key for `session`? And can you give samples of data you get in both cases?

Comment: Actually the id isn't really important, I altered the code a bit, but without losing the really important parts.

Answer (score -1):

What storage engine are you using for your table? If you're using MyISAM, consider switching to InnoDB which handles row level locking and other good stuff. There is a performance cost using InnoDB, so you'll need to determine if it's appropriate for your application.

**Edit 2: Answer is incorrect, please disregard.**